# How to change all occurrences of a word in all files in a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, replace

I was in the process of creating a `User` class where one of the methods was `get_privileges();`.

After hours of slamming my head into the keyboard, I  finally discovered that the previous coder who I inherited this particular database spelled the word "**privileges**" as "**privelages**" in the MySQL database, and thus also everywhere in the hundreds of files that access these "**privelages**" it is spelled that way.

Is there a way in Linux (*Ubuntu Server*) that I can go through every place in the `/var/www` folder and replace "**privelages**" with "**privileges**", so that I don't have to deal with this typo and code around it?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A variation that takes into account subdirectories (untested):

```
find /var/www -type f -exec sed -i 's/privelages/privileges/g' {} \;
```

This will `find` all files (not directories, specified by `-type f`) under `/var/www`, and perform a `sed` command to replace "privelages" with "privileges" on each file it finds.

Comment: Thanks - for people on a Mac with BSD sed. You'll need to add an extension to the -i argument.  

Like so: `sed -i "" 's/prive...`

Comment: If you only want to run `sed` on the files that contain the misspelling (which you will want to if your project contains thousands of files), you can do `grep -l -r "privelages" /var/www | xargs -I "@" sed -i 's/privelages/privileges/g' @`

Comment: using grep and then sed is probably worse performing than just using sed, as it means opening and reading every file twice

Comment: Beware doing this in a directory that has a .git folder. This can corrupt the contents!

Comment: I know this question is tagged linux but for Mac, I have to add `-e` after `sed -i`.

Answer (score 8):

Check this out: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-replace-string-words-in-many-files/

```
cd /var/www
sed -i 's/privelages/privileges/g' *
```

Comment: You will need to add a `find`, or use a shell which allows you to glob all files in all subdirectories (hint: `**/*` does this in some shells) if you want to recurse subdirectories. This is a FAQ; search for similar questions. Sympathies to you for having to cope with an illiterate predecessor ...

Answer (score 3):

I generally use this short script, which will rename a string in all files and all directory names and filenames.  To use it, you can copy the text below into a file called `replace_string`, run `sudo chmod u+x replace_string` and then move it into your `sudo mv replace_string /usr/local/bin` folder to be able to execute it in any directory.

NOTE: this only works on linux (tested on ubuntu), and fails on MacOS.  Also be careful with this because it can mess up things like git files.  I haven't tested it on binaries either.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This will replace all instances of a string in folder names, filenames,
# and within files.  Sometimes you have to run it twice, if directory names change.


# Example usage:
# replace_string apple banana

echo $1
echo $2

find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e "s/$1/$2/g" {} \;  # rename within files
find ./ -type d -exec rename "s/$1/$2/g" {} \;    # rename directories
find ./ -type f -exec rename "s/$1/$2/g" {} \;  # rename files
```