# unix find and replace text in dir and subdirs

Tags: perl, unix, sed, grep, replace

I'm trying to change the name of "my-silly-home-page-name.html" to "index.html" in all documents within a given master directory and subdirs.

I saw this: [Shell script - search and replace text in multiple files using a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648862/shell-script-search-and-replace-text-in-multiple-files-using-a-list-of-strings).

And this: [How to change all occurrences of a word in all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905662/how-to-change-all-occurances-of-a-word-in-all-files-in-a-directory/)

I have tried this:

```
grep -r "my-silly-home-page-name.html" .
```

This finds the lines on which the text exists, but now I would like to substitute 'my-silly-home-page-name' for 'index'.
How would I do this with sed or perl?
Or do I even need sed/perl?

Something like:

```
grep -r "my-silly-home-page-name.html" . | sed 's/$1/'index'/g'
```

?

Also; I am trying this with perl, and I try the following:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/my-silly-home-page-name\.html/index\.html/g' *
```

This works, but I get an error when perl encounters directories, saying "Can't do inplace edit: SOMEDIR-NAME is not a regular file, <> line N"

Thanks,
jml

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905662/how-to-change-all-occurances-of-a-word-in-all-files-in-a-directory/

Comment: I'm also asking a question about perl, and in general what the advantage of getting into one methodology over the other would be.

Comment: I'm also specifically wondering about a solution to the perl problem regarding directories...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec \
   perl -i -pe's/my-silly-home-page-name(?=\.html)/index/g' {} +
```

Or if your `find` doesn't support `-exec +`,

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 \
   perl -i -pe's/my-silly-home-page-name(?=\.html)/index/g'
```

Both pass to Perl as arguments as many names at a time as possible. Both work with any file name, including those that contains newlines.

---

If you are on Windows and you are using a Windows build of Perl (as opposed to a cygwin build), `-i` won't work unless you also do a backup of the original. Change `-i` to `-i.bak`. You can then go and delete the backups using

```
find . -type f -name '*.bak' -delete
```

Comment: that works better (at least it writes to more files), but i still get errors regarding the "can't do inplace edit" thing.

Comment: @jml, oh! I think you used the code that was missing `-type f`. It was there for just a few seconds! That's what's preventing "is not a regular file".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -e 's/my-silly-home-page-name\.html/index\.html/g' -i
```

Basically it gathers recursively all the files from the given directory (`.` in the example) with `find` and runs `sed` with the same substitution command as in the `perl` command in the question through `xargs`.

Regarding the question about `sed` vs. `perl`, I'd say that you should use the one you're more comfortable with since I don't expect huge differences (the substitution command is the same one after all).

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do this but you can use:

```
find . -name oldname.html |perl -e 'map { s/[\r\n]//g; $old = $_; s/oldname.txt$/newname.html/; rename  $old,$_  } <>';
```

Fyi, ***grep*** searches for a pattern; ***find*** searches for files.