# UNIX: How to change all instances of a string within all files in a directory

Tags: unix, ubuntu

My question is basically the same as this previous question...

[How to change all occurrences of a word in all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905662/how-to-change-all-occurances-of-a-word-in-all-files-in-a-directory/8905787#8905787)

...except I'm trying to change the reference to a header file.

For example,I'm trying to change `[lessthan]abc/filename.h[greaterthan]` to `"filename.h"`, is this even possible using the same syntax, or should I be looking to whip myself up a quick program to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You could do this quite easily with a number of tools.  The most common choices would probably be sed or perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with `sed`:

```
sed -i -e 's,<abc/filename.h>,"filename.h",' *
```